# Can we show percentage increase in line grapgh Tableau?

Tags: percentage, tableau-api

I am using Tableau version 8.1. Suppose the x axis is different month years (201310,201311 etc) and the y axis is the percentage of revenue increase for that month. I want to show the percentage increase in revenue in a line graph with respect to the previous month. 
Currently i am getting the percentage increase . 
For example 
from oct-nov there is 5 % increase:  200$
from nov-dec there is 4 % increase:  450$
from jan-feb there is 3% increase:   750$
But the line graph is displaying based on the value of percentage increase instead of revenue generated.
For example the graph is like this
columns shelf :  Month year
rows shelf  : percentage increase in revenue
So what is happening is that even though there is increase in revenue the graph is showing decreasing line graph (based on the percentage increase) from 5% to 4% to 3%.
What i want is that it should show the line graph upwardly as there is increase in revenue
from previous month. Can some one suggest how to accomplish this?

Regards
Gautam S

Comment: Please, post a table with data you have also both viz: actual and desired. It is hard to issue understand from your text.

Comment: Hi Hellion,Thanks.I put the percentage increase on the label of marks shelf and the actual revenue in rows shelf. It works out perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want then is not to chart the percentage increase in revenue (which shows declining rate of growth), but to chart the revenue itself (which shows increasing growth) and possibly having the rate of growth as a tooltip or label.

Put revenue on the rows shelf.

Put percentage increase in revenue onto the "Tooltips" box or the "Text" box in the Marks card.